# Compilation error when calling _tcsstr and assigning to a wchar_t*

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am getting a compilation error when trying to build a C++ project which previously worked.

The code follows:

```
const wchar_t* pdest;
pdest = _tcsstr(ConnStr, Name);
```

The error follows:
Error   10  error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'const wchar_t

I'm using Visual Studio 2008.  The error message explains the problem well, but I know this program used to compile, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is dangerous.  _tcsstr is a TCHAR macro, so it's definition can change depending on whether or not UNICODE is defined.  wchar_t is fixed.  The error you're seeing is due to this exact problem - the environment is using the single-byte version of _tcsstr (likely becasue UNICODE is not defined).

Don't just define UNICODE.  Fix the code first.  Either use TCHAR macros for both, or the wide character functions.

Comment: I was compiling in debug mode instead of a unicode mode which is why this worked previously, but not now.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

_tcsstr is for use with TCHAR. Depending on compile settings, this is either char or wchar_t.

So either use `TCHAR`, or `wcsstr`

Answer (score 0):

That should fix this issue:

> Property -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Character Set : Use multi-Byte Character Set.